# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int em count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Já vi várias respostas sobre essa mensagem

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Porém, tudo que indicaram fazer não deu certo. Só dá erro quando utilizo o `count`.

Código:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DML.NK_CO_SEQ_LOTERICA)
FROM DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_LOTERICA AS DML
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_PEDIDO AS DMP ON DMP.CO_LOTERICA = DML.CO_LOTERICA
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_PRODUTO AS DMPR ON DMPR.NK_CO_SEQ_PRODUTO = DML.CO_PRODUTO
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_ATENDIMENTO AS DMA ON DMA.CO_LOTERICA = DMP.CO_LOTERICA
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_TITULO AS DMT ON DMT.CO_PRODUTO = DML.CO_PRODUTO AND DMT.CO_LOTERICA = DML.CO_LOTERICA
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_LOG_ENTRADA AS DME ON DME.CO_PRODUTO = DML.CO_PRODUTO
WHERE DML.CO_PRODUTO IS NOT NULL
AND DME.CO_PRODUTO <> 0
```

Comment: Os tipos dos campos de que fazem a ligação são iguais?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DML.NK_CO_SEQ_LOTERICA)`

Comment: Veja se não está acontecendo um produto cartesiano indevido gerando um valor de "count" "explosivo"

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o [COUNT_BIG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT_BIG(DML.NK_CO_SEQ_LOTERICA)
FROM DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_LOTERICA AS DML
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_PEDIDO AS DMP ON DMP.CO_LOTERICA = DML.CO_LOTERICA
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_PRODUTO AS DMPR ON DMPR.NK_CO_SEQ_PRODUTO = DML.CO_PRODUTO
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_ATENDIMENTO AS DMA ON DMA.CO_LOTERICA = DMP.CO_LOTERICA
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_TITULO AS DMT ON DMT.CO_PRODUTO = DML.CO_PRODUTO AND DMT.CO_LOTERICA = DML.CO_LOTERICA
JOIN DW_XCAP.XCAP.DM_LOG_ENTRADA AS DME ON DME.CO_PRODUTO = DML.CO_PRODUTO
WHERE DML.CO_PRODUTO IS NOT NULL
AND DME.CO_PRODUTO <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro acontece quando o valor excede o tamanho especificado da coluna.

Um exemplo sobre como acontece esse erro: Você tem 3 colunas (`c1`, `c2` e `c3`) definidas como `INTEGER`, `c1 = ([c2]*[c3])`. Se os dados em `c2` e/ou `c3` forem valores muito grande, `c1` vai exceder o limite permitido para `INTERGER` e você receberá esse erro.

Para corrigir esse erro, você tem que verificar o tamanho da coluna de destino. Uma dica é reduzir os valores permitidos nas colunas de origem da fórmula ou aumentar o tamanho da coluna de destino.